# c++ multithread optimization

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, vector, montecarlo

in my code I have 2/4 threads performing montecarlo simulations. Each of them runs a number of experiments and they all collect the results into a stl vector.
My question is this: suppose each thread runs 1000 experiments sequentially. Is is better to store the result into the shared vector one at the time, or every once in a while? If they wait until they have some consistent amount of data, writing into the vector will take longer, so I'm not sure whether the second solution is necessarily better than the first one.

PS each experiment is numerical computation, so no IO operations.

Thanks

Comment: You could have a shared lock-free stack and push results into that.

Answer (score 8):

If you are going to wait until all the results are computed before you use any of the results, preallocate space for 4,000 results in the vector and have each thread write into one range of elements in the vector.  No locking is required because no two threads access the same element in the vector.

If you want to use the results as they are computed, use some sort of a concurrent queue data structure instead of a vector.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only putting 2000 to 4000 elements in the vector I doubt it would make much of a difference either way.

Do whatever is most natural for the algorithm.  If that doesn't work well enough look into doing it the other way.

After thinking about it for a bit, it might serve both purposes (simplicity and speed) to have each thread store results to a local vector then copy the contents of the local vector to the 'global' vector (protected by a lock) when the thread is done.  Of course, that's as long as whatever's waiting for the results can wait until a thread is fully finished before getting an update.

Answer (score 0):

a singly linked list may be a better choice than vector here.

If there is only one thread reading and one thread writing to a fifo .. you don't need any synchronization . The trick is to keep at least one 'dummy' element always in the list, and fifo is empty if head == tail . The head and tail pointers can be manipulated for push and pop, such that there is no need for synchronization..

Using this .. you can make several Q's .. which will not need any synchronization 
If new/delete is taking time .. you can have Q's to hold reusable elements.

best of luck .

remember .. Exactly one reader, and Exactly one writer .. no more, no less .
the trick is createa LOT of Q's like this , Q to recycle objects also .. and
you'll not need any thread synchronization stuff ...

If your Q's do run empty .. just a sleep() / wakeup() functionality is needed.

and in case i haven't already said .. Exactly one reader, and Exactly one writer.

Comment: Access to the pointers still needs to be synchronized, either using a lock or an atomic.  A linked list may decimate performance; linked lists are for most use cases extraordinarily inefficient compared to other sequence containers (whether the performance cost is substantial depends entirely on the OP's use case, of course.)

Comment: @James .. no .. access to pointer need NOT be synchronized .. that's the beauty  .. think conceptually .. if there is a long singly linked list .. will both thread ever change same memory location !

Comment: Even if only one thread is modifying a pointer and the other thread is just reading it, access to it needs to be synchronized.  This is always possible and is highly likely at the head and tail nodes if the linked list is used as a queue.

Comment: @James pls write the code .. any memory location will not be have simultaneous RW or WW ...

Comment: Actually, now I am confused.  You are suggesting that a linked list can be used as a queue, but only one thread is going to modify the list.  How are elements to be removed from the queue?  Perhaps you can demonstrate what you are trying to explain.

Comment: That doesn't explain how elements are removed.  Is one thread adding elements to the queue (using `push_back`) and the other thread removing elements from the queue (using `pop_front`)?